# Changing the reserve memory of C++ vector

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector, resize

I have a vector with 1000 "nodes"

```
 if(count + 1 > m_listItems.capacity())
     m_listItems.reserve(count + 100);
```

The problem is I also clear it out when I'm about to refill it.

```
m_listItems.clear();
```

The capacity doesn't change. 
I've used the resize(1); but that doesn't seem to alter the capacity. 
So how does one change the reserve?

Comment: Is your system short of memory? Reserving like that means that adding n items to it uses O(n^2) time and at most n+100 objects worth of space plus rounding error. Letting the vector extend itself would be less code, O(n) time, and on most implementations use at most 2*n space plus rounding.

Comment: My system is very short on memory.(embeded).. The code was really just an example of what I'm kinda thinking of implementing. For the most part I get 1000 item chunks from the "table" so it makes sense to resize in the same frequency.  The CLEANUP was my primary concern.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
vector<Item>(m_listItems).swap(m_listItems);
```

will shrink `m_listItems` again: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm (Herb Sutter)

If you want to clear it anyway, swap with an empty vector:

```
vector<Item>().swap(m_listItems);
```

which of course is way more efficient. (Note that swapping vectors basicially means just swapping two pointers. Nothing really time consuming going on)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while swap() is extremely cheap, constructing the temporary copy of m_listItems in the first case is going to require copying of every element in the vector. So while clearing the vector entirely (setting capacity to 0) is cheap. Downsizing it otherwise is not.

Comment: jalf indeed. but that sequence is essentially the same that would be needed if vector would have a shrink() function itself. reallocation would be needed anyway :/

Comment: but your point is good, since in c++1x, vectors can move their elements to the new place. my code should simply look   vector<Item>(std::move(m_listItems)).swap(m_listItems); then i think

Comment: I was looking for the clear.. Not really sizing down. I'm using the vector as a tool for populating a list. Honestly I thought it was implemeneted with a linked list. Seems I was wrong.. Oh well it's fast enough now.

Comment: @litb: moving it will probably not work, as the result would be the same as: m_listItems.swap(m_listItems); which is a no-op.

Comment: dalle, hmm right the buffer will indeed still have the same dimension -.- silly me

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the vector as others have suggested, and as described in http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm but be aware that it is *not* free, you're performing a copy of every element, because the vector has to allocate a new, smaller, chunk of memory, and copy all the old contents over. (The swap operation is essentially free, but you're swapping with a temporary initialized with a copy of the original vector's data, which is *not* free)

If you know in advance how big the vector is, you should allocate the right size to begin with, so no resizing is necessary:

```
std::vector<foo> v(1000); // Create a vector with capacity for 1000 elements
```

And if you don't know the capacity in advance, why does it matter whether it wastes a bit of space? Is it worth the time spent copying every element to a new and smaller vector (which is what std::vector(v).swap(v) will do), just to save a few kilobytes of memory?

Similarly, when you clear the vector, if you intend to refill it *anyway*, setting its capacity to zero seems to be an impressive waste of time.

*Edit*:

> baash05: what if you had 1000000 items
>   an 10 megs of ram. would you say
>   reducing the amount of overhead is
>   important?

No. Resizing the vector requires *more* memory, temporarily, so if you're memory-limited, that might break your app. (You have to have the original vector in memory, *and* the temporary, before you can swap them, so you end up using up to twice as much RAM at that point). Afterwards, you might save a small amount of memory (up to a couple of MB), but this doesn't matter, because the excess capacity in the vector would never be accessed, so it would get pushed to the pagefile, and so not count towards your RAM limit in the first place.

If you have 1000000 items, then you should initialize the vector to the correct size *in the first place*.

And if you can't do that, then you'll typically be better off leaving the capacity alone. Especially since you stated that you're going to refill the vector, you should definitely reuse the capacity that has already been allocated, rather than allocating, reallocating, copying and freeing everything constantly.

You have two possible cases. Either you know how many elements you need to store, or you don't. If you know, then you can create the vector with the correct size in the first place, and so you never need to resize it, or you don't know, and then you might as well keep the excess capacity, so at least it won't have to resize upwards when you refill your vector.

Comment: what if you had 1000000 items an 10 megs of ram.   would you say reducing the amount of overhead is important?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this technique from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=397748)

```
std::vector< int > v;
// ... fill v with stuff...
std::vector< int >().swap( v );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `swap` it with a new vector that has desired capacity.

```
vector< int > tmp;
old.swap( tmp );
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't reallocate a vector to a lower capacity than it ever has; you can only allocate it larger.  There are good reasons for this; among them is that the reallocation process is hugely computationally intensive.  If you really need to have a smaller vector, free the old one and create a new one that's smaller.  That's actually computationally much simpler than having the vector actually resize smaller.

Comment: Depends how it was allocated - you either let it go out of scope, or you call delete. I don't think this is good advice compared with the swap.