# C++ trick to ensure deallocation of a vector, but compilation problems with GNU g++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

The following code demonstrates a trick that ensures complete deallocation of a vector:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class tvector : public vector<T>
{
    public:
    typedef vector<T> base;
    void swap(tvector<T>& v) {
        // do some other stuff, but omitted here.
        base::swap(v); }
};

int main()
{
    tvector<int> tv1;
    // imagine filling tv1 with loads of stuff, use it for something...

    // now by swapping with a temporary declaration of an empty tvector that should
    // go out of scope at the end of the line, we get all memory used by tv1 returned
    // to the heap
    tv1.swap(tvector<int>());
}
```

Well, this works using Visual C++ (cl.exe), but using GNU g++ does not compile, with this error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘tvector<int>::swap(tvector<int>)’
test.cpp:10:7: note: candidate is: void tvector<T>::swap(tvector<T>&) [with T = int]
```

Is this an error in g++, or is my code genuinely wrong C++ code?

My workaround for this deallocation trick using g++ is this:

```
int main()
{
    tvector<int> tv1;
    {
        tvector<int> t;
        tv1.swap(t);
    }
}
```

Any opinions on this?

Comment: My opinion is that since it is about to go out of scope you should do nothing at all and let the destructor clean it up.

Comment: No. Don't inherit from standard containers. Don't take this risk.

Comment: How is this any improvement over the traditional `swap` trick? Also note that C++11 makes this less of an issue, thanks to `shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `shrink_to_fit` has no guarantees. It is up to the implementation to decide whether the deallocation should take place. The real question is "How is `std::vector<int>().swap(v);` any improvement over `v = std::vector<int>()`".

Answer (score 12):

This is all well known. The standard textbook trick to deallocate the contents of a vector is:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// Do stuff with v

std::vector<int>().swap(v); // clears v
```

Note that the reverse doesn't work:

```
v.swap(std::vector<int>()); // compile time error
```

because you are trying to bind a temporary to a non const reference, which is forbidden.

Visual Studio allows this as a non standard extension, but pushing the warnings level up to /W3 (IIRC) triggers a "non standard extension used" warning.

In C++11 (and technically in C++03 too !), you can simply do

```
v = std::vector<int>();
```

or, if you are into verbosity (C++11 only), there is

```
v.clear(); // or v.resize(0);
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

but the standard doesn't guarantee anything about whether the request to shrink is to be fulfilled.

You can use this if you really need to, but please, **do not inherit from standard containers**. This is not a safe thing to do: you run the risk of calling the wrong destructor.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: `clear()` doesn't change the capacity of the vector, only the size. No memory is deallocated.

Comment: Awesome. This explains it, I was just doing it the wrong way round. Thanks to Alexandre.

Answer (score 3):

You call the `swap` method with temporary, which is not stored anywhere. It can't be taken as a reference because from the compilers point of view it's not stored anywhere. `tvector<int>` versus `tvector<int>&`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Joachim. It must be that Visual C++ is just more tolerant and stores this tempoary somewhere?

Comment: One should note that while you can't take a non-const reference of a temporary, const references to temporaries are fine. But in this case a const reference won't work, because the argument has to be modified. However, you can take an Rvalue reference (introduced in C++11) of a temporary to implement move semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [this idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319292/changing-the-reserve-memory-of-c-vector/319306#319306) to free a vector's reserved memory:

```
tvector<int>().swap(tv1);
```

Passing a temporary variable to `swap` isn't permitted, because `swap` takes a non-const reference (in other words, it needs a non-temporary variable that it can modify).  (I'm surprised that Visual C++ accepts this code.)

If you use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) instead of gcc, it tries to explain this for you:

```
test.cc:35:14: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'tvector' cannot
      bind to a temporary of type 'tvector'
    tv1.swap(tvector());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:22:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'v' here
    void swap(tvector& v) {
```

The correct version of the idiom works because it creates a variable that stays created for the entire statement and then passes a non-temporary parameter.